# JSON Decode to Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been tasked with trying to map a json file to a database a sample of the json is given below:

```
configurationItems":[  
  {  
     "configurationItemVersion":"1.0",
     "configurationItemCaptureTime":"2014-12-05T10:22:51.751Z",
     "configurationStateId":1,
     "relatedEvents":[  ],
     "awsAccountId":"val",
     "configurationItemStatus":"v",
     "resourceId":"fg",
     "ARN":"ggggg",
     "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
     "availabilityZone":"us-east-1b",
     "configurationStateMd5Hash":"ggd45",
     "resourceType":"AWS::EC2::Instance",
     "resourceCreationTime":"2014-01-06T10:37:37.000Z",
     "tags":{  
        "Name":"",
        "cirrushq_id":""
     },
```

using the following code I have been able to map the entries down to resource creation time but now wish to map the tags to a different table called tag

```
<?php 


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","json_map");
$response = array(); 
$res=array(); 
$json = file_get_contents('C:\Users\Richard\Desktop\test.json'); 

if($json!=null){ 
$decoded=json_decode($json,true); 
//$decode= var_dump($decoded); 
//$ss=$decode["array"]; 
//echo $decoded['number']; 

if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
{ 
foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
//for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 

 { 


$configurationItemVersion=$configurationItems["configurationItemVersion"]; 
echo "<br />","configuration_Item_Version:",$configurationItemVersion,"<br        />"; 

  $configurationItemCaptureTime=$configurationItems["configurationItemCaptureTime"    ]; 
echo "configurationItemCaptureTime:",$configurationItemCaptureTime,"<br />"; 

$configurationStateId=$configurationItems["configurationStateId"]; 
 echo "configurationStateId:",$configurationStateId,"<br />"; 

 $awsAccountId=$configurationItems["awsAccountId"]; 
 echo "awsAccountId:",$awsAccountId,"<br />"; 

$configurationItemStatus=$configurationItems["configurationItemStatus"]; 
echo "configurationItemStatus:",$configurationItemStatus,"<br />"; 

$resourceId=$configurationItems["resourceId"]; 
echo "resourceId:",$resourceId,"<br />"; 

$ARN=$configurationItems["ARN"]; 
echo "ARN:",$ARN,"<br />"; 


$awsRegion=$configurationItems["awsRegion"]; 
echo "awsRegion:",$awsRegion,"<br />"; 
 etc etc

  $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO        configuration_item(configuration_item_version,configuration_item_capture_time,configuration_state_id, aws_account_id, configuration_item_status, resource_id, arn, aws_region, availability_zone,configuration_state_md5_hash, resource_type, resource_creation_time)


VALUES('$configurationItemVersion','$configurationItemCaptureTime','$configurationStateId','$awsAccountId','$configurationItemStatus','$resourceId','$ARN','$awsRegion','$availabilityZone','$configurationStateMd5Hash','$resourceType','$resourceCreationTime' )")or die("Insert Failed ".((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));; 

}// check if row inserted or not 
if ($result) { 
    // successfully inserted into database 
    $response["code"] = 1; 
    $response["message"] = "successfully stored configuration items "; 

    // echoing JSON response 
    echo json_encode($response); 
} else { 
    // failed to insert row 
    $response["code"] = 2; 
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred."; 

    // echoing JSON response 
    echo json_encode($response); 
} 

} 
} 



?>
```

I tried duplicating the code into a separate file and altering the insert statement to

```
if(is_array($decoded["configurationItems"])) 
{ 
foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems) 
//for($i=0;$i>sizeof($decoded["configurationItems"]);$i++) 

 { 


$Name=$configurationItems["Name"]; 
echo "<br />","Name:",$Name,"<br />"; 

$cirrushq_id=$configurationItems["cirrushq_id"]; 
echo "<br />","cirrushq_id:",$cirrushq_id,"<br />"; 




$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO     tag(name, cirrushq_id)


VALUES('$Name','$cirrushq_id' )")or die("Insert Failed ".((is_object($con)) ? mysqli_error($con) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));;
```

but to no avail it just returns unknown index Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote, I'm not completely sure to understand what's the cause of your problem.

However, let me point out a few inconsistencies I spotted:

1) Since you speak about tags (plural), I'm guessing you'd like to have more than one tag associated to each `configurationItems` element. In this case your JSON should be:

```
...
"tags":[{
    "Name":"",
    "cirrushq_id":""
 },{
    "Name":"",
    "cirrushq_id":""
 }]
...
```

2) According your JSON, to access tag name and tag cirrushq_id you should do:

```
$Name=$configurationItems["tags"]["Name"];
$cirrushq_id=$configurationItems["tags"]["cirrushq_id"];
```

and in the case you take into consideration my point 1), you'd have to make another loop through the tags:

```
foreach($decoded["configurationItems"] as $configurationItems)
{
...
   foreach($decoded["configurationItems"]["tags"] as $tags)
   { 
      $Name=$tags["Name"]; 
      echo "<br />","Name:",$Name,"<br />"; 

      $cirrushq_id=$tags["cirrushq_id"];
      echo "<br />","cirrushq_id:",$cirrushq_id,"<br />";

      // clearly, the INSERT query should also be inside this nested loop 
   }
}
```

3) From what you wrote in the tag `INSERT` query, you have a lowercase `name` column, while in your JSON, the index `Name` is uppercase...I know it's trivial but sometimes, when there's not another pair of eyes that can double-check your code, it's just simple stuff like this that make you waste a lot of time.

Hope to have been of help!